# How to change tab page title when I activate other tab page

Tags: android, tabpage

1st page:
[image: "setTitle 1st Tab" text should be changed when I activate other tab page]

2nd page:
[image: "setTitle 2nd Tab" should be shown when I click (activate) second tab page]

Hi I'm using Android ActionBarSherlock: and I'm having trouble:
How to change title bar text when I change tab page, sorry for this simple question but It is taking me a lot of time (unsuccessfully)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I Think create TextView Dynamically.

```
 TextView tv=new TextView(this);
  tv.setText("Your Title");
```

Or if using same XML TextView Then:-

```
   TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xmlname);
   tv.setText("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set the title with :

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("yourTitle");
```

each time you change tab.